# iOS Face ID/Touch ID Lock Screen Conflict in willEnterForegroundNotification

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, face-id

I have code that puts a blurred `UIVisualEffectView` over the current window when the `didEnterBackgroundNotification` notification is fired. It then tries to reverse this when `willEnterForegroundNotification` is fired (simplified for easy reading):

```
class AutoBlur {
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appDidEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appWillEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func appDidEnterBackground() {
        blur()
    }

    @objc func appWillEnterForeground() {
        guard UserState.isScreenLockEnabled else {
            unblur()
            return
        }
        let authContext = LAContext()
        authContext.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: "test") { success, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard success else {
                    return
                }
                unblur()
            }
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

While this approach generally works, when testing the Face ID functionality of app I found the following anomaly:

1. Open the app
2. Turn the screen off on the device
3. Wake the device
4. Swipe up on the device's lock-screen

Expected results: The device should unlock, and then my app should run its Face ID evaluate code to un-blur the view.

Actual results: The swipe-up action is undercut by my app's Face ID evaluation code. It prevents the user from being able to swipe up on their lock-screen, effectively locking them out of their device.

Is there some state I should be monitoring or some other event that's safer to respond to for triggering my Face ID evaluation?

Comment: Same problem:/ Did you find some solution?

Comment: I ended up having to use `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` instead. This required me to use my own `isLocked` state flag to control when the app tried to un-blur.